# Shared connection over multiply threads

Tags: c++, mongodb

Is it possible to create pointer of `DBClientConnection` and use it in multiply threads?

```
connection = new DBClientConnection();
connection->connect("localhost");
```

Then use `connection` in thread.

Is it safe to access to `connection` simultaneously?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. DBClientConnection is not thread safe and should not be shared with more than one thread. You might also want to check ScopedDbConnection, which is backed by a connection pool and closes the socket for you upon destruction.