# Thread safeness at MongoDB C++ driver regarding indirect connection usage through cursor

Tags: c++, multithreading, mongodb

This question is a kind of follow up of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10397724/shared-connection-over-multiply-threads), regarding thread safeness at Mongo C++ driver. As reference, I'm using [legacy-1.0.2 version](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver/releases/tag/legacy-1.0.2) of the driver.

Thus, after reading the answer to that question, it is clear that it is not safe that two threads use at the same time the same `DBClientConnection`. However, what about "indirect" usage of connections due to cursors? Let's me explain with an example.

Consider a program with a connection pool (i.e. an array of `DBClientConnection` objects) and a way of ensuring that only one thread at a time uses a given instance of the pool. Let's consider the following case:

- Thread T1 takes connection C1 from the pool. Nobody except T1 is accesing C1 from that time.
- Thread T1 do a `query()` operation using C1 and gets a `DBClientCursor` object (let's name it U1). To be clear, I'm referring to [this particular operation](http://api.mongodb.org/cxx/legacy-1.0.2/classmongo_1_1_d_b_client_connection.html#a29ceacce8b959b1d12f7918aa404da5a).
- Thread T1 returns C1 to the pool, as, once the U1 object is get, connection object itsef is no longer useful for him.
- T1 starts processing the results of U1 in a long `while(u1->more())` loop. Let's assume that the cursor is so large that not all the results can be returned in a first bunch (at wiring protocol level), so a connection to the DB is needed to return new results through the network wiring protocol implemented by the driver.
- While T1 is doing that work, a new thread (T2) gets C1 from the pool, i.e. the connection previously used by T1.
- T2 does some operation using C1 while T1 is still using U1 (a cursor generated through C1).

Would that case be problematic? Although, the program is honouring the thread safeness "contract" regarding `DBClientConnection` objects (i.e. only one thread at a time can access to the same `DBClientConnection` instance) and `DBClientCursor` (i.e. only one thread at a time can access to the same `DBClientCursor` instance), there could be indirect concurrent access to the same connection (at internal level) due to cursors and I don't know if that could be a problem.

*Rationale of this question*: I have a program in which the above case may occur and I'm getting weird and semi-random crashes due to exception at `DBClientCursor` methods, in particular `next()/nextSafe()` and `more()`. The case of `more()` is particularly weird... that's a method so simple that shouldn't fail (except for concurrency problems, of course)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not legal to do what you suggest: internally the DBClientCursor contains a pointer to the DBClientBase object, and it calls methods on it. Therefore, you must keep the connection out of the pool until you destroy the cursor.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Just one doubt remain... what do you mean by "destroy the cursor"? Invoking kill() operation on it?

Comment: Better would be to only re-use the connection after the destructor of the DBClientCursor object has run. The DBClientCursor::kill method doesn't actually null out the pointer to the DBClientBase. If you inadvertently called another method on the DBClientCursor after kill, you could still race. Now, you might say you won't do that, but the only way to be sure is to destroy the cursor object by calling its dtor.

Comment: Thank you again for so accurate feedback!